# Data Modeling with a Time Dimension

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Would it be better to create a time dimension with hh:mm:ss altogether or would it be better to split them up into 3 dimensions since separately they will take up less space?

What would you recommend and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was just creating a separate time dimension with a row for each possible combination of hour, minute, and second.

I did this vs creating 3 separate tables for hours, minutes, and seconds each to keep the number of joins down and not make the database too clustered with tables.

I kept it separate from my date table to keep the number of rows down and making performance slower.

Seems to work pretty well, thanks for the feedback everyone.

Comment: One question... if all you need is the HH, MM and SS, with no other descriptive info, why not just put them right onto your fact table & completely avoid any join at all?

Comment: I did add descriptive info after the table was created.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a Date Dimension ?
The Date Dimension is a key dimension in data warehousing as it allows to analyze data in different aspects of date. Apart from the standard date attributes like year, quarter, month, day , hour, min ..., the date dimension can be extended to richer analysis

Working with star schema model is a best practice. Date dimension is called [a conformed dimension](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/conformed-dimension/).

Spliting up in 3 dimension = more joins = complex queries.

Comment: There are limitations with this approach: 1) The granularity of each date record will have to go down to the second, making for a very long dimension table, and 2) Depending on implementation, it could be hard to compare, say, activity at noon each day.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a time dimension with the following (and maybe more) columns on the dimension table?

- HH
- MM
- SS
- AM PM Indicator
- HH:MM:SS
- Nickname (e.g. 'noon')
- Daypart (e.g. 'morning')
- HH Military (here you might put 14 for 2 pm)

The key could be interesting here. Perhaps it's a sequence but, alternatively, you could use HHMMSS as the key (with leading zeros). I don't think performance will differ significantly.

Comment: you mean 86400 rows (24 * 60 * 60)? If so, that's what I decided to do in the end.

Comment: Great! Yes, when you look at that math, if you extended this out to the date dimension, you'd end up with 31,536,000 rows per year and 315,360,000 for ten years of data.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you want to keep your date dimension's granularity such that it can be joined to every fact table that has the date key.  In most cases, the day-level granularity satisfies this objective.  By adding granularity down to the time-of-day (seconds) you're now limiting this particular date dimension to only those fact tables organized to the time level. Moreover, a date dimension down to the seconds level will be 86400 (and a 1440x for a minutes-level) times larger than the date-level dimension.  In my view, and I believe the best practice, is to implement two dimension tables, one for the date-level granularity and a second table for the time-of-day granularity.